# How to enter an entire array values into a cell in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with values. I want to enter the values from 5 cells into one other cell, one after the other.

Let' say I have five different cells in a column like this.
1
2
3
4
5

So I created an array and pushed the values into the array. Then I have a script to assign `cell.setValue(array)` to the cell. The cell displays only the first value of the array. I want to display all values one below the other, but inside the same cell.

How do I do it with script?

I can do it like the below version, but the execution time is high.

```
for(var i = 0; i<variations.length; i++)
    {
      var cval = s.getRange(lsrn, 3).getValue();
      if(i ==variations.length-1){s.getRange(lsrn, 3).setValue(cval+variations[i]);}
      else{s.getRange(lsrn, 3).setValue(cval+variations[i]+"\n");}
    }
```

Here, the `variations` is the array.

I want to do it without having to copy the values of the cell time and time again.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your code snippet is slow be cause of the many calls to SpreadsheetApp, see [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services)

- You can singnificatly optimize it by retrieving the value of `getRange(lsrn, 3)` only once
- Then feed the values of your array plus `\n` into a dummy string within the loop
- Set the result into your spreadsheet only once - after exiting the loop

**Sample:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lsrn = 1;
  var variations = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var string = "";
  var cval = s.getRange(lsrn, 3).getValue();
  for(var i = 0; i<variations.length; i++)
  {
    if(i ==variations.length-1){
      string+=variations[i];
    }
    else{
      string+=variations[i]+"\n";
    }
  }
  s.getRange(lsrn, 3).setValue(cval+"\n"+string);
}
```

Comment: I figured it out after posting the question, but this is the correct answer. Thank you.